# iFrame Text Not showing up on Firefox but works on Chrome (document.body.innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

Fellow coders, I am running into this issue, I've a iframe with ID="graph", I am trying to output this html while page loads, but for some reason it's not working on firefox but works great on chrome.

```
<script language="javascript">
 var text = "We are creating your Memory Performance Graph, Please hold.";
 document.getElementById('graph').document.body.innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Any recommendations on where it went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The DOM interface for an HTMLIFrameElement object specifies 'contentDocument' as the name of the IFrame document, not "document" by itself.
I was able to get a version of your message to appear in an iframe using

```
 var text = "We are creating your Memory Performance Graph, Please hold.";
 var iFrameObj = document.getElementById('graph');
 var docObj = iFrameObj.contentDocument || iFrameObj.document;
 docObj.body.innerHTML = text;
```

The only reason to include " || iFrameObj.document" was in case Chrome does not support the standard attribute name (untested).

In testing I placed the code in a window onload event handler to avoid potential timing issues with accessing the iframe element before finalisation

---

**Addendum 2023**

The following HTML works when saved and loaded in Firefox, as it did when this answer was first posted. *However* it doesn't work as a stack snippet on SO. I suspect the reason is that the snippet runner treats the IFRAME element as not from the same origin as the parent document, and as a result returns `null` (or maybe `undefined`) for the document object value stored in `docObj`;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">

   <title>iframe document</title>

</head>
<body>

<iframe id="graph"></iframe>

<script>"use strict";
window.onload = event => {

 var text = "We are creating your Memory Performance Graph, Please hold.";
 var iFrameObj = document.getElementById('graph');
 var docObj = iFrameObj.contentDocument || iFrameObj.document;
 docObj.body.innerHTML = text;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works perfectly on chrome, but it's not outputting on firefox, any idea why? @Traktor53